# Returning data from promise to a variable using map

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise

I want to return the data to a variable.
I have resolved the promise and making it print to console. I want that the data should be access outside and can be used by a variable.
I want whatever values are there in console.log(x) , should come outside the loop in a variable ( say variable name z)

```
 var libobj =await service.getdata(); //----------> returning from service file and libobj is returning  promise (fullfilled)

// var z; -----Data needed here or below the map loop

libobj.map( (res: any) => 
(res.then((x : any )=>console.log(x)) )); //--------> console .log(x) printing all  the data needed
```

Comment: don't know what "getdata()" returns, but if it is fetch call it need to be "libobj.json()"

Comment: what is the type of `libobj`? Is it an array of promises?

Comment: @JafarJabr - get data returns promise

Comment: @NalinRanjan yes it is array of promise

Comment: Check [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: `let values = []; (async () => values = await Promise.all(libobj);)()`, something along those lines. A better example can be produced if you can come-up with a value for `libobj`, a value suitable to run the test.

Comment: @NalinRanjan The code you wrote won't work (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/8376184). Instead, you can do `const values = await Promise.all(libobj)`

Comment: Thanks @FZs, I have updated. Also, it's merely an example for the OP to see how can he use `Promise.all`...

Comment: promise.all worked,,,thx

Answer (score -1):

Following is an example to showcase [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)...

```js
let createAPromise = (x) => new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(() => { console.log(`Resolving ${x}`); res(x)}, x));


async function test() {

  const libobj = [300, 500, 700].map(x => createAPromise(x));

  const values = await Promise.all(libobj);

  console.log('Resolved all with', values);
}

test();
```

This example is only to highlight a way of `Promise.all` to obtain a final value from a collection of promises...

Comment: I replied to your comment (I didn't notice your answer). The point I was trying to make there was that assigning an external value from a `.then` callback doesn't work, but I see that your answer didn't have this problem. :) `let` or `const` makes little difference here.